# Is it recommended to run NodeJS on an IIS server?

Tags: node.js, iis

Im moving to MEAN stack, and I am migrating an application originally developed with .NET framework to Angular and Node, but using mssql with Node, so its not really a mean solution. Anyway, so far Im fascinated with the simplicity and coding speed of Node.

Im utilizing Nodemon at the server, and developing from home in Angular. I opened port 3000 at the server and I point my angular http calls to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000. Everything is perfect so far; but at some point I will have to move to production and that's where my doubts begin.

I was reading several articles on the Internet about running Node on an IIS by utilizing reverse proxies, URL rewrite, installing PM2, installing Node as a service, etc; but I am not quite convinced this is the right way to expose the APIs to the internet. Some articles say IIS is "the way to go" while others say it may cause conflicts when Node crashes (?).

The question is then, is it recommended to run Node over IIS, which is what I know and Im confortable with, or should I use Express to expose my APIs to the internet?

Thanks.

Comment: I was there. My biggest issue was the installation of an SSL certificate. This may help you: https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/how-to-install-ssl-certificate-on-node-js/ PM2 will be required even if you dont use IIS since its a reliable way of running Node.JS application.

Comment: Nice Q for a debate... I have a node app running on a Windows VM together with AlwaysUp. I had tons of issues when node was erroring out which I fixed with try-catch on every route. dont know about express but iis works just fine

Comment: Can IIS and Express coexist? I mean, can I host my Angular APP on IIS (www.domain.com) for a specific domain and have my APIs running on Express for a different domain (api.domain.com) at the same server without having any issue?

Comment: Why do you think Windows is a must (IIS is Windows only) in the big picture? Running everything on Linux is cheaper and most people (PHP/Python/Go/Node.js) go that way.

Comment: Hi Lex. Ive been dealing with Windows for almost 20 years now. Moving to Linux will imply to learn from scratch, and it won't be an immediate solution.

Comment: IIS is a great choice for deploying application. The advantage of it is GUI and easy to troubleshoot. Microsoft develops many modules for it so that users can extend and use.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. So running IIS will imply not to use Express, correct?

Comment: I have tried to use IIS to host a simple nodejs application before, and it runs very well without express.